# cut first two characters in second column

Tags: text-processing, cut

I have a file with list of American and Canadian states/provinces and it looks like this:

```
    id,name,abbreviation,country,type,sort,status,occupied,notes,fips_state,assoc_press,standard_federal_region,census_region,census_region_name,census_division,census_division_name,circuit_court
"1","Alabama","AL","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","1","Ala.","IV","3","South","6","East South Central","11"
"2","Alaska","AK","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","2","Alaska","X","4","West","9","Pacific","9"
"3","Arizona","AZ","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","4","Ariz.","IX","4","West","8","Mountain","9"
"4","Arkansas","AR","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","5","Ark.","VI","3","South","7","West South Central","8"
"5","California","CA","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","6","Calif.","IX","4","West","9","Pacific","9"
"6","Colorado","CO","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","8","Colo.","VIII","4","West","8","Mountain","10"
"7","Connecticut","CT","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","9","Conn.","I","1","Northeast","1","New England","2"
"8","Delaware","DE","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","10","Del.","III","3","South","5","South Atlantic","3"
"9","Florida","FL","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","12","Fla.","IV","3","South","5","South Atlantic","11"
"10","Georgia","GA","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","13","Ga.","IV","3","South","5","South Atlantic","11"
"11","Hawaii","HI","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","15","Hawaii","IX","4","West","9","Pacific","9"
"12","Idaho","ID","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","16","Idaho","X","4","West","8","Mountain","9"
"13","Illinois","IL","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","17","Ill.","V","2","Midwest","3","East North Central","7"
"14","Indiana","IN","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","18","Ind.","V","2","Midwest","3","East North Central","7"
"15","Iowa","IA","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","19","Iowa","VII","2","Midwest","4","West North Central","8"
"16","Kansas","KS","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","20","Kan.","VII","2","Midwest","4","West North Central","10"
"17","Kentucky","KY","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","21","Ky.","IV","3","South","6","East South Central","6"
"18","Louisiana","LA","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","22","La.","VI","3","South","7","West South Central","5"
"19","Maine","ME","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","23","Maine","I","1","Northeast","1","New England","1"
"20","Maryland","MD","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","24","Md.","III","3","South","5","South Atlantic","4"
"21","Massachusetts","MA","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","25","Mass.","I","1","Northeast","1","New England","1"
"22","Michigan","MI","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","26","Mich.","V","2","Midwest","3","East North Central","6"
"23","Minnesota","MN","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","27","Minn.","V","2","Midwest","4","West North Central","8"
"24","Mississippi","MS","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","28","Miss.","IV","3","South","6","East South Central","5"
"25","Missouri","MO","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","29","Mo.","VII","2","Midwest","4","West North Central","8"
"26","Montana","MT","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","30","Mont.","VIII","4","West","8","Mountain","9"
"27","Nebraska","NE","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","31","Neb.","VII","2","Midwest","4","West North Central","8"
"28","Nevada","NV","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","32","Nev.","IX","4","West","8","Mountain","9"
"29","New Hampshire","NH","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","33","N.H.","I","1","Northeast","1","New England","1"
"30","New Jersey","NJ","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","34","N.J.","II","1","Northeast","2","Mid-Atlantic","3"
"31","New Mexico","NM","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","35","N.M.","VI","4","West","8","Mountain","10"
"32","New York","NY","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","36","N.Y.","II","1","Northeast","2","Mid-Atlantic","2"
"33","North Carolina","NC","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","37","N.C.","IV","3","South","5","South Atlantic","4"
"34","North Dakota","ND","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","38","N.D.","VIII","2","Midwest","4","West North Central","8"
"35","Ohio","OH","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","39","Ohio","V","2","Midwest","3","East North Central","6"
"36","Oklahoma","OK","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","40","Okla.","VI","3","South","7","West South Central","10"
"37","Oregon","OR","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","41","Ore.","X","4","West","9","Pacific","9"
"38","Pennsylvania","PA","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","42","Pa.","III","1","Northeast","2","Mid-Atlantic","3"
"39","Rhode Island","RI","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","44","R.I.","I","1","Northeast","1","New England","1"
"40","South Carolina","SC","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","45","S.C.","IV","3","South","5","South Atlantic","4"
"41","South Dakota","SD","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","46","S.D.","VIII","2","Midwest","4","West North Central","8"
"42","Tennessee","TN","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","47","Tenn.","IV","3","South","6","East South Central","6"
"43","Texas","TX","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","48","Texas","VI","3","South","7","West South Central","5"
"44","Utah","UT","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","49","Utah","VIII","4","West","8","Mountain","10"
"45","Vermont","VT","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","50","Vt.","I","1","Northeast","1","New England","2"
"46","Virginia","VA","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","51","Va.","III","3","South","5","South Atlantic","4"
"47","Washington","WA","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","53","Wash.","X","4","West","9","Pacific","9"
"48","West Virginia","WV","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","54","W.Va.","III","3","South","5","South Atlantic","4"
"49","Wisconsin","WI","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","55","Wis.","V","2","Midwest","3","East North Central","7"
"50","Wyoming","WY","USA","state","10","current","occupied","","56","Wyo.","VIII","4","West","8","Mountain","10"
"51","Washington DC","DC","USA","capitol","10","current","occupied","","11","","III","3","South","5","South Atlantic","D.C."
"60","Alberta","AB","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
"61","British Columbia","BC","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
"62","Manitoba","MB","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
"63","New Brunswick","NB","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
"64","Newfoundland and Labrador","NL","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
"65","Nova Scotia","NS","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
"66","Ontario","ON","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
"67","Prince Edward Island","PE","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
"68","Quebec","QC","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
"69","Saskatchewan","SK","Canada","province","30","current","occupied","","","","","","","","",""
```

and I would like to make this:

```
name,country
Alabama,US
...
Wyoming,US
Alberta,Ca
Saskatchewan,Ca
```

First the US states and then the Ca provinces.

My solution is this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat north_america.csv | head -n1 | cut -d',' -f2,4 > title
cat north* | tail -n +2 | cut -d',' -f2,4 | tr -d '"' | sort -t','  -k 2  | head -n10 > Canada
cat north* | tail -n +2 | cut -d',' -f2,4 | tr -d '"' | sort -t','  -k 2  | tail -n +11  > USA

cat USA | rev | cut -c-1 --complement | rev > file1
cat Canada | rev | cut -c 1-4 --complement | rev > file2

cat title > states
cat file1 >> states
cat file2 >> states
```

My question is, if I can 'cut' somehow first two characters from second column? Instead of 'head' and 'tail' I will use

```
cat north* | tail -n +2 | cut -d',' -f2,4 | tr -d '"' | sort -t','  -k2,2r >> states
```

and then I would make a 'cut' command. But I don't know how to make it.
And I don't want to use head and tail and spliting the file on two files. I would like to make easier approach.

I will appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need for this is:

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '{print $2,$4}' file
```

The `-F,` sets the field separator to `,` and the `-vOFS=","` sets the output field separator to `,`. Then, we just print the 2nd and 4th field of each line. On your example file, this returns:

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS="," '{print $2,$4}' file 
name,country
"Alabama","USA"
"Alaska","USA"
"Arizona","USA"
"Arkansas","USA"
"California","USA"
"Colorado","USA"
"Connecticut","USA"
"Delaware","USA"
"Florida","USA"
"Georgia","USA"
"Hawaii","USA"
"Idaho","USA"
"Illinois","USA"
"Indiana","USA"
"Iowa","USA"
"Kansas","USA"
"Kentucky","USA"
"Louisiana","USA"
"Maine","USA"
"Maryland","USA"
"Massachusetts","USA"
"Michigan","USA"
"Minnesota","USA"
"Mississippi","USA"
"Missouri","USA"
"Montana","USA"
"Nebraska","USA"
"Nevada","USA"
"New Hampshire","USA"
"New Jersey","USA"
"New Mexico","USA"
"New York","USA"
"North Carolina","USA"
"North Dakota","USA"
"Ohio","USA"
"Oklahoma","USA"
"Oregon","USA"
"Pennsylvania","USA"
"Rhode Island","USA"
"South Carolina","USA"
"South Dakota","USA"
"Tennessee","USA"
"Texas","USA"
"Utah","USA"
"Vermont","USA"
"Virginia","USA"
"Washington","USA"
"West Virginia","USA"
"Wisconsin","USA"
"Wyoming","USA"
"Washington DC","USA"
"Alberta","Canada"
"British Columbia","Canada"
"Manitoba","Canada"
"New Brunswick","Canada"
"Newfoundland and Labrador","Canada"
"Nova Scotia","Canada"
"Ontario","Canada"
"Prince Edward Island","Canada"
"Quebec","Canada"
"Saskatchewan","Canada"
```

To remove the quotes, you could pass that through `tr`:

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '{print $2,$4}' file | tr -d \"
```

To get the output *exactly* as you show (so no `"`, `US` instead of `USA` and `Ca` instead of `Canada`), you can use (assuming GNU `sed`):

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '{print $2,$4}' file | sed 's/"//g; s/USA/US/; s/Canada/Ca/'
```

Or, if you don't have GNU `sed`:

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '{print $2,$4}' file | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/USA/US/' -e 's/Canada/Ca/'
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using `sed` here (I think there are very few cases where `awk` needs `sed`; besides, regex is expensive)... `tr -d \" <infile | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $2, (NR==1?$4:substr($4,1,2))}'`

Comment: @don_crissti the only point is that I find the syntax of the `s///` operator far less cumbersome than awk's `sub` and `gsub`. And given that we're only parsing a few dozen lines, I felt clarity trumps efficiency in this instance.